# how to compare two cell values from excel sheet in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Close

817.4

841.35

847.15

838.6

845.55

841.8

843.85

849

823.75

I want to do this (841.35-817.4)*100/841.35 operation programatically using python. I am reading the data from a .csv file in python.please can you help me with this.I want to read the values of the rows and then compare them. i am not able to figure out how to get values of a particular cell value.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: "I am not able to figure out how to get values of a particular cell value" - well , how did you read the values to these "cells" ? If you can add some details about what you tried, we can look into it.